# How to add a hourly calendar table to analyse hourly data using Power BI?

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop, data-modeling

I have an Excel file containing hourly data for the last 1 year.

Example (FactResale):

```
DateTime            PurchaseAmt     SalesAmt
.                   .
.                   .
.                   .
26-09-2023 10:00:00 1750
26-09-2023 11:00:00 2350
26-09-2023 12:00:00 4500
.
.
```

I have calendar dimension table with Date, Year, Month, Day. Note: this table's granularity is day. Where as the Fact table's granularity is hour.

In my table visual I want to show DateTime column and purchase/sales which will show the hourly value of purchase/sales.

Is it correct to join the calendar table to the FactResales on Date and DateTime, or is there a better way to model when doing analysis by the hour (for example: a calendar table for DateHour?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a separate table for times. Have one dim table at date granularity and a second dim table at time granularity. Your fact table should have two columns - one for date and one for time.

Comment: For simple reports (model size less than 100MB) does it make sense to create separate dimension for date and time, or I was thinking if I can just do with the fact table only. I tried this and can get the desired output with the model having just one fact table with the DateTime column.

Comment: Having date time columns means your column cardinality sky rockets. It is best practice to split them no matter the model size.

Comment: Any other questions?

Comment: Is there a standard date and time table script (M or DAX) that you'd recommend?

Comment: For DAX, use the following: https://www.sqlbi.com/articles/creating-a-simple-date-table-in-dax/

Comment: For Power Query, this one is very good:https://gorilla.bi/power-query/date-table/

Comment: There isn't one for times but they are easy enough to generate. Imke Feldmann's Github has useful time functions in there too.

Comment: When you say cardinality sky rockets - are you referring to the fact table compression reduction?

Comment: Yes but cardinality also affects relationship performance too.